# Circle in classical guitar music

Tags: classical-guitar

How do you play a natural E on classical guitar with a complete circle above it? I have tried playing a harmonic on the 12th fret, but this doesn't work with the fingering written for the majority of the piece.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the exact notation?

Comment: is there a number in the circle?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:C
%%score T1
V:T1           clef=treble-8
% 1
[V:T1] "  ○"e'
```

then e-string over 12th fret is pretty much the only practical natural harmonic. However, you can always also use an *artificial* harmonic, e.g. b-string 5th fret and flageolett-pinch the string with the left hand over the 17th fret.

If you instead mean

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:C
%%score T1
V:T1           clef=treble-8
% 1
[V:T1] "  ○"e
```

then this should actually not be played on the e-string at all. It is best on the A-string over the 7th fret, alternatively on the low E-string over the 5th fret.